# Solve with Cauchy Integral theorem: $\oint_C \frac{1}{z(2z+1)^2} \, \text{d}z$ but solve with partial fractions

Tags: complex-integration, partial-fractions

I want to solve this integral $\oint_C \frac{1}{z(2z+1)^2}\, \text{d}z$ with parcial fractions using Cauchy Integral theorem.
There's no other way to solve without being partial fractions? Trying to put a $2z$ in evidence and then move on to the numerator being $\frac{1}{2z}$ and so using Cauchy theorem?

C is a unitary circle

Comment: What is $C$? Depending on your contour you don't need to do partial fractions.

Comment: Oh sorry, its a unitary circle

Comment: Solve for $a,b,c:$ $$\frac1{z(2z+1)^2}=\frac{a}{z}+\frac b{2z+1}+\frac c{(2z+1)^2}$$

Comment: a =1, b = -2, c = -2.
If I now substitute this in the integral, and apply Cauchy's theorem, I will have:

$2i\pi(0)$ + $2i\pi (-1/2)$? And the last term that has the squared factor, I don't know... I need to find the root of (2z+1)^2 and use in residue?